# Link Button on the page and set it as default button, work fine in IE but not in Mozila

Tags: asp.net, mozilla, linkbutton

I have a **link button** on the page and set it as default button, It works fine in IE but not working in Mozila Firefox. Does anybody have any clue how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What I have check it, Link Button could not be set as default in Mozila

Comment: No my friend; you have to set the DefaultButton property of the HtmlForm (asp:Form) on the page. Set it to the id of the LinkButton and it will work automatically.

Comment: And if you want multiple default buttons on a single form, use an asp:Panel control; group your controls accordingly and set the DefaultButton property of the panel. Just be sure to put the button in that respective panels.

Comment: Thanks, that's right, now event is fired and working but now get another problem doing so, I am calling an encryption method on OnClientClick, that's is called when I click on the link button, but not not called when I hit enter button

Comment: I think what happen here is, when hitting enter button, javascript WebForm_FireDefaultButton method called and click event is fired and it ignores others event like onclientClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this kind of issue with FF3 and ASP.NET linkbuttons. This seems to be a bug with FF3 (not sure), but the script that fixed is given below:

```
var __defaultFired = false;

function WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, target) {
    var element = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (!__defaultFired && event.keyCode == 13 && !(element && (element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea"))) {
        var defaultButton;

        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser)
            defaultButton = document.getElementById(target);
        else
            defaultButton = document.all[target];

        if (defaultButton) {
            if(typeof(defaultButton.click) != "undefined")
                defaultButton.click();
            else
                eval(unescape(defaultButton.href.replace("javascript:", "")));

            event.cancelBubble = true;

            if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Keep it at the end of the page so that it overrides the `WebForm_FireDefaultButton` method rendered by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 14):

The `DefaultButton` property is not supported for use with a `LinkButton`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

The easiest solution is to include a dummy Button on your page with `style="display:none"`, set that as the defaultbutton and give it the same event handlers as your LinkButton.

Comment: It might have to do with the way it's implemented… I noticed the Javascript behind the functionality uses the `click` property of the button. However, whilst IE implements a click property for links, other browsers do not. This is why the current implementation of the DefaultButton functionality only works for LinkButtons in IE.

Comment: Wow... this is by FAR the simplest, easiest-to-implement workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first Stack Overflow write, wow :-)

asp.net:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="lbHello">
    First name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbHello" Cssclass="button" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClick="lbHello_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('.button').eventClick(); });

$.fn.eventClick = function() {
    function eventClick(a) { 
            if (a && typeof (a.click) == 'undefined') {
                a.click = function () {
                    var result = true;
                    if (a.onclick) result = a.onclick();
                    if (typeof (result) == 'undefined' || result) {
                        eval(a.getAttribute('href'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return eventClick($(this).get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

work only first time we press enter in textbox. After adding some text in textbox and then pressing enter ,default button will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

I think its very simple, just add onkeypress js event of textbox where post back is required.

```
txtUserName.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)
 __doPostBack('" + btnLogin.UniqueID + "','')");
```

hope this will be helpful.