# jQuery replacement for Default Button or Link

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-2.0

As everyone knows, that default button doesn't work in FF, only IE. I've tried to put in the  tag or in the  and it's not working. I've found a js script to fix this issue, but for some reason it's not working for me. This script for a submit button, i need to use it for a LinkButton, which is should be the same.

Link:

```
  <div id="pnl">
    <a id="ctl00_cphMain_lbLogin" title="Click Here to LogIn" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphMain$lbLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Login1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Log In</a>
    <input name="ctl00$cphMain$UserName" type="text" id="ctl00_cphMain_UserName" />
    <input name="ctl00$cphMain$UserName" type="text" id="ctl00_cphMain_UserName1" />
  </div>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pnl").keypress(function(e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            $("a[id$='_lbLogin']").click();
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

I know that i can override original function "*WebForm_FireDefaultButton*"
in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938957/link-button-on-the-page-and-set-it-as-default-button-work-fine-in-ie-but-not-in) post, but i really wanted to get this one to work.

Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to fixing linkbuttons here: http://www.sentia.com.au/2009/03/fixing-the-enter-key-in-aspnet-with-jquery/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $btn = $('.form_submit');
  var $form = $btn.parents('.form');

  $form.keypress(function(e){
      if (e.which == 13 && e.target.type != 'textarea') {
          if ($btn[0].type == 'submit')
              $btn[0].click();
          else
              eval($btn[0].href);
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11778517/177710) for an updated version of this script that works with dynamically loaded content and several forms on one page.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Larry Flewwelling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704072/177710) or rather [Michael Cindric's](http://www.sentia.com.au/2009/03/fixing-the-enter-key-in-aspnet-with-jquery/), I came up with a modified and updated version of that javascript snippet. I've documented more detailed information on why and how in [this blog post](http://shades-of-orange.com/post/2012/08/02/Asynchronously-posting-back-a-form-by-hitting-the-Enter-key-%E2%80%93-in-ASPNET-WebForms-using-jQuery.aspx), but let me summarize the important changes:

1. Works with dynamically loaded content
2. Works with any number of "forms" on the same page

And here it is:

```
$('body')
  .off('keypress.enter')
  .on('keypress.enter', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && e.target.type != 'textarea') {
      var $btn = $(e.target).closest('.jq-form').find('.jq-form-submit');
      if ($btn.length > 0) {
        if ($btn[0].type == 'submit') {
          $btn[0].click();
        }
        else {
          eval($btn[0].href);
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expand your selector.

```
$("#pnl > input")
```

Which will then catch the input click for all the controls in the panel.

Comment: Looks Good, but what if some1 highlights text in this panel/div and press ENTER?