# Why, if I have two <asp:TextBox>, "Enter" (on keyboard) become disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, input, submit

Code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

if I click on an input field and I press Enter, it submits nothing. Why? And how can I decide which page to call, pressing Enter, for each input box?

Comment: do you have some validators on that TextBox-es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both boxes to separate Panel and set DefaultButton for each Panel.

**UPDATE** DefaultButton will work if you use Button, LinkButton works only in IE, there are some workarounds :

[set linkbutton as default button for asp:panel in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581369/set-linkbutton-as-default-button-for-asppanel-in-asp-net)

[Reusable Page_PreRender function in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642269/reusable-page-prerender-function-in-asp-net)

Comment: Can you give to me an Example?

Comment: `<asp:Panel ID="panelCerca" runat="server" DefaultButton="SubmitButton"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>` doesnt works...

Comment: check out my reply on `Niranjan Kala` answer :(

Comment: Uhm...I figure it out how to do it with LinkButton. It works perfect, also with IE7 :) Which troubles?

Answer (score 2):

you set the forms default button:

```
<form id="Form1"
    defaultbutton="SubmitButton"
    runat="server">
```

Or you can do it in code - Page_load:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSearch.UniqueID;
```

Another helpful tip is that you can set the `default button` on `asp:panel`'s too. Wrap your 'forms' into a Panel or Multiple panels in form with will give your ability to set multiple `submit` button per `Panel Control`:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlForm1" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Uhm, but I can't refeer to an href position with <asp:Button> or <asp:LinkButton>, and with <asp:HyperLink> it doesnt works :(

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery to resolve it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        var button = $("#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>");
        if (button != null && code == 13) {
            button.click();
        }
    });
})
```

or in C#

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = SubmitButton.UniqueID;
```

[HtmlForm.DefaultButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultfocus%28v=vs.80%29)

[Using Panel.DefaultButton property with LinkButton control in ASP.NET](http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/)