# Default button not triggered in Panel

Tags: asp.net, panel

Whys is not lblMasterPhoneNumbers onclick method trigger when i press enter in the textbox?

```
       <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" DefaultButton="lbMasterPhoneNumber" runat="server">  
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMaster" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxSearchActive" EnableTheming="false" />    
            </td>
            <td>
                <%--<asp:Button ID="btnSearchMaster" CssClass="SearchButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearchMaster_Click" CausesValidation="false" EnableTheming="False" />--%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="margin-right:3px; color:white">                       
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMasterPhoneNumber" runat="server" Text="Phone number" ForeColor="White" onclick="lbMasterPhoneNumber_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ActivateLoadingIndicator()" /> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMasterCDR" runat="server" Text="CDR" ForeColor="White" onclick="lbMasterCDR_Click" /> | &nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMasterSMS" runat="server" Text="SMS" ForeColor="White" onclick="lbMasterSMS_Click" />

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: do you mean **javascript:ActivateLoadingIndicator()** is not triggered?

Comment: Which browser ?Should work in IE. Problems have been reported in Firefox over the years. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938957/link-button-on-the-page-and-set-it-as-default-button-work-fine-in-ie-but-not-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msdn states that defaultbutton property does not support linkbutton http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

Comment: The work around is by using javascript. if you have not seen already refer these posts.http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/  http://henry-chong.com/2011/10/using-the-defaultbutton-property-on-asppanel-controls-with-linkbuttons/